# SWReveal revealToggle() not working

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I've been trying to get my project up and running using the [SWRevealController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) classes. I am nearly done writing the basic code for my App so there is already quite a bit of code inside this project. I have tried this inside another project before and it did work.

***What I am doing:***
I have two ViewControllers. One of them being a SWRevealViewController holding absolutely nothing and one BasicViewController who is just holding a button. I added a Button to the ViewController as well as a IBOutlet. In the ViewDidLoad() Method I added a target to the Button to be fired when pressed:

***Inside BasicVC:***

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

***In the Storyboard:***
I created a segue from the SWRevealViewController to the BasicViewController. (reveal view controller set controller)

***Outcome:***
The code compiles perfectly, but results in the button being pressed without anything actually happening. **However**, if I create a new project and do exactly the same thing, the SWRevealViewController appears.

---

***Q:*** Is there anything I could do in order to get the solution for this problem? Apparently there's something interfering with the SWReavealViewController class, because it is perfectly working in the other projects.. I am just too "blind" / new to Swift to actually find it.

***What I already tried:***
Was that I set a breakpoint for when the button is being pressed aka the view being loaded. What I noticed was, that in the test project *without* any other code, the debugger actually went inside the SWRevealController class, but in my project *with* a whole lot of other code, it actually does not.

***EDIT:*** It actually does go into the class.

---

***Thanks*** for reading until here! I'd really appreciate any help. Maybe I am just too "noobie" to find the issue and it actually is just a tiny little issue..
Kind regards.

Comment: ***UPDATE*** Solved the first issue. I had to set the entry point for the application to be the SWRevalViewController, not the BasicViewController. This, however, creates a whole lot of new problems. Though I am sure I can fix these on my own, or someone can answer this thread.

Comment: If you share the repo I could give it a look

Comment: @MauricioChirino - Thanks for offering your help! I already diagnosed the issue and fixed all the issues. It was an issue with the initialVC not correctly initialising. Since I fixed it, everything is working as it should.